# How to disable Feign's auto retry logic

Tags: spring-cloud-feign, feign

As it is mentioned in the Feign's documentation, by default, will automatically retry `IOException`s.

We have some another `retry` logic in our project and I want to prevent Feign's. Is there any easy way to disable it? Or should write my own retryer?

We are using Spring cloud's open feign library.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to provide your own `Retryer` if you wish to change the default retry behavior.  It can be applied directly to the Feign.builder or by registering it as a Bean.  Either way, you must implement the `feign.Retryer` interface.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do nothing at least from version `spring-cloud-starter-openfeign 2.2.6`.
Spring disables retries in the `FeignClientsConfiguration`. So Feign doesn't do retries for `IOException`.

```java
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public Retryer feignRetryer() {
        return Retryer.NEVER_RETRY;
    }
```

It is impossible to do retries for an exception other than `IOException` on the Feign level by the way.